# How do I read value from code behind on html page? Or any better way of doing that?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, web-services

**Solution: I end up creatting a WCF that accepts a get/post request, then place JQuery within the html page that retrieves the value and hands it off to the web service**

I have a html page like below where I will be doing posting to a web site for registrations and my credentials are not suppose to show on the client side.

My question is how/what is the best way of reading the values from code behind or web service or any other way ?

```
    <FORM NAME="web_form" ACTION="https://website.com/registration.php" METHOD="POST">
        <TABLE WIDTH=961 BORDER=0 CELLPADDING=2 CELLSPACING=0> 
            <TR>
                <TH WIDTH=380>
                    <P ALIGN=RIGHT><i>Encrypted Username:</i> 
                    </P>
                </TH>
                <TD WIDTH=573>
                    <P><A NAME="username"></A><INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="username" VALUE="HOW TO GET VALUE???" SIZE=20 STYLE="width: 1.69in; height: 0.23in"></P>
                </TD>
            </TR>
            <TR>

..............
.................
```

Comment: Not really my area of expertise, but it looks like you're posting to PHP instead of ASP.NET...?

Comment: What values from the code behind are you talking about?  Can you post your code behind and explain what value you want?

Comment: @Abe: if you look at the `username` where the value needs to fill in and i am not sure how i will be passing the value since its a html page or should i use web service or something? but the bottom line is, i should hiding the values from public.

Comment: @Greg: does not matter what web site i am posting to but the point here how i will be reading the values or what is the best way to deal.

Comment: As I understand you are using https (http with ssl tunel) so your values will be encrypted before sending to server. So they would not be visible for other on network...

Comment: @Abu Hamzah: It matters because data doesn't get sent back to the ASP.NET server for plain HTML pages.  The `<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="MyPage.aspx" id="aspnetForm">` generated by MyPage.aspx is how the data gets back to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch the input box in to an ASP control?

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="username" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Then in your code behind:

```
this.username.Text
```

Comment: no i can not chagne to asp.net controls because its a html page

Comment: @AbuHamzah: Then you don't have a way of accessing it. ASP is a server-side language. Your best bet is either to submit the form to an ASP page, or use AJAX and an ASHX/ASMX and pass the variable off.

Comment: will you help me or tell me how i will be reading from asmx page? i do have .asmx page that returns string.

Comment: @Abu Hamzah: whether it's extension is html or aspx is immaterial.  You can use .net controls.  Just have your IIS server configured to run .html pages through the .net processor.

Comment: i can not change the IIS server configuration its a big drama if i go with that route.

Comment: @AbuHamzah: You create a web service that accepts a get/post request, then place javascript within the html page that retrieves the value and hands it off to the web service. Then ASP can use the value how you deem fit.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a little more that we need to know to make a perfect suggestion, but there's tons of different ways that you could do this.

If you have access to the registration page -- which would be ideal -- you could send a base64encoded string via the URL or via hidden input in the form field posted on submit to the reg page and then base64 decode it before passing in.  Similarly, you could salt the value with any number of different methods and "un-salt" it at the application.

Merely hiding it in a hidden input field probably won't suffice here as that code is certainly available on a view source, unless the data inside it is sufficiently obfuscated.

There are javascript obfuscators that will do a sufficient job, but they'll be unavailable if the user has javascript turned off.  It won't affect 99% of the users out there, but it is something to think about.

Perhaps you could set this up as a dynamic page (not HTML) and set some sort of a constant?  Perhaps a session variable that you then call in at the registration page?

Comment: in one of my page (aspx) i did use constant and post and when it comes to .aspx i dont have a problem but i am having difficulty to pass value to html page? not sure how i will be doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on client side with JavaScript:

`INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="username" VALUE="some value" onclick="CopyValue()" />
    function CopyValue() 
{ 
  var myValue = document.getElementById('username').value;

}`

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but just a suggestion. In HTML always try to keep your values in quotes. Always a good programming practice. Will definitely help you if you are trying to move from HTML to XHTML or XML. Good Luck!